# Search txt file not finding full word

Tags: php, search, text

i am trying to run a simple search within a PHP script, i am not able to work out what is going wrong.
i am searching for the word 'James' within the txt file, i know that it is in there however i am getting no results.
if i however replace "/James/" with "/J/" i get the results that i should.
i will paste the content of the txt file below the code

```
<?php
$lines = file('ServicesResults.txt');
$lines_two = preg_grep("/James/", $lines);

foreach($lines_two as $name){
    echo "$name<br>";   
}
?>
```

------txt file content-----
Breanna says hello 
Joe says hello
Steven says hello
Lyn says hello
Len says hello
James says hello

-----Results of search "/J/" -----
Joe says hello
James says hello

----No results of search "/James/"----

----No results of search "/Ja/"----

i am sorry, this seems like a really stupid question, i just can't work out what i am doing wrong

Thanks all
James

Comment: strpos should be used to simply find a string in a string

Comment: Have you figured out how to do it now, with `hakre's` answer and my comments below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With `hakre's` blessing I hope, have come up with the following solution:**

You will need to use the [**file_get_contents()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function in order to use [**hakre's code below**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346324/1415724).

### (tested)

Assuming in ServicesResults.txt file:

------txt file content-----
Breanna says hello 
Joe says hello
Steven says hello
Lyn says hello
Len says hello
James says hello

Using `/James/` will return `James says hello`
Using `/Ja/` will return `James says hello`
Using `/J/` will return `Joe says hello James says hello`

### PHP

```
<?php

$text = file_get_contents('ServicesResults.txt');

$lines = explode("\n", $text);

$lines_two = preg_grep("/Ja/", $lines); // modify as required

foreach($lines_two as $name){
    echo "$name\n";   
}
```

Full credit goes to [**hakre**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre)

Comment: OK, I worked out what was going on.<br>

I am trying to get powershell to send information via email, the txt file i was using was generated by powershell, for testing I replaced all the content of the txt file with simple information (james says hell, etc)<br>
If i create a black txt file normally the code works perfectly however if it is generated from powershell then the code behaves as I described.<br>
I Still don't know what the difference is between creating the txt file manually and using powershell however this seems to be the problem.

thanks very much to everyone for your help<br>

Comment: @user2701631 Ok, well it glad it worked out. If you would like to click the checkmark to the left, will be as an accepted answer and your question will no longer be left as "unanswered". Cheers :)

Comment: @Fred-ii: No, he does not will need to use file_get_contents. He only needs to understand that with the data provided in his question, this can not be reproduced. It is not a matter of a specific function or the code given. it's the matter that OP is not clear about where exactly the problem is and much more important that the presenteation currently given on SO is totally in the wrong place of the subject. But failure is always an option, so probably leave OP alone with the problems and give this some time. Most problems just solve over time.

Comment: @hakre I understand and agree with you 100%. There is always success after failure.

Answer (score 0):

Your question indeed is sort of stupid (no offence please) because what you have there just works:

```
<?php

$text = <<<BUFFER
Breanna says hello 
Joe says hello
Steven says hello
Lyn says hello
Len says hello
James says hello
BUFFER;

$lines = explode("\r\n", $text);

$lines_two = preg_grep("/James/", $lines);

foreach($lines_two as $name){
    echo "$name\n";   
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/private/f5bdf0fdfdb55d ; Program Output:

```
James says hello
```

So about whatever / wherever you think the problem is, you do not ask about it specifically. The information given does not allow to reproduce your problem. I just copy and pasted this from your question.

Comment: That's strange, I got *"Breanna says hello Joe says hello Steven says hello Lyn says hello Len says hello James says hello"* as output. (PHP 5.4)

Comment: @Fred -ii-: yes, most likely because of the explode key. you need to have `"\n"` there.

Comment: I thought your code would have outputted only `James says hello` instead of the whole content in `$text`

Comment: Yes it does, klick the demo link to see how it works. You need to save the code-example in a file-format with CRLF as line-seperator (windows).

Comment: Aahhh yes I get it now, thanks. Another notch on my (preverbial) belt of added information, cheers.

Comment: So basically, the OP needs to use `file_get_contents` in conjunction with your code. I figured it out ;-)

Comment: Would you mind if I put it in as an answer while giving you credit?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, this is at least narrowing down the issue. when i use your code it works perfectly however it is when i get from the txt file that i get the same issue, i am unable to put more then 1 letter in the search. if i put J in the search i get the two results, if you put James i get no results

Comment: @user2701631 I modified `hakre's` code to produce results. Using `/Ja/` will return `James says hello`  and Using `/J/` will return `Joe says hello James says hello` while using a/your `.txt` file. Yet I haven't heard from `hakre` about using his code as an answer. I don't want to overstep my bounds, as it were.

Comment: i am happy to give credit to whoever you like as long as i get it to work :)

Comment: @user2701631 Have a look at my answer then. I am giving credit to `hakre` for this of course. I only added to it.